# Android database query not returning any results

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

This is my code to query my android database.

```
int lastID = -1;

String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MAIN + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " > " + lastID;

Log.i(LOG, selectQuery);
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

if (c.moveToFirst())
{
    ...
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

For some reason every time this runs (I have debugged it) it always falls into the else of the if statement and I dont know why. This led me to believe that my query is wrong but I cannot see how it is wrong. I know that the table name and column name is correct because it is a globally defined variable. Is anyone able to spot my mistake? Thanks

Comment: The most obvious reason would be that your table has no data matching your selection.

Comment: yeah no I checked that with a database viewer, it has data

Comment: Sure it was the same database you were looking at?

Comment: try and remove the condition `" WHERE " + KEY_ID + " > " + lastID;`  and see if it returns any data if it still don't return any data, then im guessing either the table has no data, you using the wrong database or `TABLE_MAIN` is not the table you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test your select like

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MAIN + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " > " + "'" + lastID + "'";
```

Some devices (this happen to me in some devices) sqlite integer only works with > 1 without simple quotes, but numbers <= 0 need simple quotes. Why? I don't know.

Comment: actually this did solve my problem after testing it again...thanks!